# Mercurial TextAuth plugin error "Parse exception: '*** failed to import extension textauth.file from C:\inetpub\auth: invalid syntax (auth, line 1)'"

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, zend-studio, mercurialeclipse

I've installed the TextAuth plugin to Mercurial to add basic authentication for pulling/pushing code.

Via Tortoise HG Mercurial interface, I get the error below, but the operation continues and authentication is accepted and working correctly, i.e, if I change the username inside the file named "auth", the old one is no longer accepted, etc.

This wasn't a problem until I started using Zend Studio with the Mercurial Eclipse plugin, the same error is thrown from Mercurial, but Zend/Eclipse doesn't continue, like the Tortoise HG workbench does, so it's stopping work completely...

Any help would be great, thanks.

```
"Parse exception: '*** failed to import extension textauth.file from C:\inetpub\auth: invalid syntax (auth, line 1)'"
```

EDIT: Here is the contents of the plain text file. It's UTF-8 without BOM.

```
david:sha512:34306d47f380e8c4:3e1abe5b38db2b56b997adca78030a1a085dcf2961413820813b9972b3d91c676921419b5b2e3953571e35a4efd8f68e95e9880b2b54756ab5c7256fb6c6cdaf
steven:sha512:589c75e34563ec0c:ba097345634e7ae5d1b577b2093563c1ed06af78e90e8197116140c22dd14745d6aaebaf05bb005a4e916114fec086b95b2d6eab1286be94c2d91f7a5d4426c
dev1:sha512:dcdb2734655344b:78531b07d09345634ab2265fc5acc3b2a92386f2ab2168ce559f6db5bf9da034fde50cbec128ebb89a210fcf918582ed366de1f0998e6c570a1ce498429a4ad
dev2:sha512:c8fc3a3456d9470:6efca993620138644d203695ced07f6aaddb0d2752fd12970639012f66a5c07b210564b9046d818bfcbc978aff5151400269b9a816ed9279a929cb46aa4a53
dev3:sha512:d26466ec818cd62a:ebc0ff463546e3456aff6e8828bbc8ff812990ddaa4f112d3d932d943598e7b27c6547c14b3786b2ef3fe955eb01e12c67aaea175bc011ae0b6eb1fa4f093ece
```

The passwords have had characters scrambled, so if you try it and it doesn't work, that's why, but they were generated by the authedit command, and are accepted during authentication.

Here is the contents of the hgrc file with obvious stuff obfuscated/changed.

```
# Generated by TortoiseHg


[web]
push_ssl = False
allow_push = *
[ui]
username = david
[paths]
repo = http://domain.com/
Live = C:\inetpub\domain.com

[auth]
repo.schemes = http
[auth]
repo.username = david
repo.password = passstring

[extensions]
textauth = C:\inetpub\textauth.py
textauth.file = C:\inetpub\auth

[textauth]
file = C:\inetpub\auth

[tortoisehg]
postpull = update
autoresolve = True
```

Comment: Can you post your auth file (with passwords modified of course)?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I've edited the question with the contents of the file. It's plain text, 791 bytes.

Comment: Perhaps it's the way you setup the plugin. It would be nice to see your configuration file (hgrc).

Comment: Hi, I've amended the contents of the hgrc file... Thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find reference to the textauth plugin online, but I suspect this is your problem:

```
[extensions]
textauth = C:\inetpub\textauth.py
textauth.file = C:\inetpub\auth
```

That's saying "load two separate extensions one called textauth and one (illegally) called textauth.file.

You want this:

```
[extensions]
textauth = C:\inetpub\textauth.py

[textauth]
file = C:\inetpub\auth
```

So just remove the `textauth.file =` line in the `[extensions]` section.

It's an easy mistake to make because when given on the command line the `[section]` and `key` syntax does become `section.key` like this:

```
hg --config ui.username=david ...
```

but in a .hgrc that's:

```
[ui]
username = david
```

Comment: This appears to be the textauth plugin: https://bitbucket.org/hstuart/hg-textauth .

Comment: Ah, thanks for tracking that down.  It confirms what I said above -- file goes in a `[textauth]` section not in `[extensions]`

Comment: Thank you for your help, worked perfectly. Seems obvious now I know! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Everything under `[extensions]` is treated as a plugin. The C:\inetpub\auth file is not a plugin, it's a file used by a plugin. You should just have (in addition to the textauth.py extension of course):

```
[textauth]
file = C:\inetpub\auth
```

This part of the documentation is where that is explained, it would have been nice if they had given an example:

> ### textauth
>
> Section that controls the behavior of the textauth extension.
>
> Supported arguments:
>
> `file`
>       The path to the file containing authentication information. The
>       contents of this file should be as described below.